# Fresh Install WP error - "The site is experiencing technical difficulties"

Tags: php, installation

Usually this kind of error is associated with some plugin, but not in my case since this is a fresh install of the latest WP version. I'm getting this error after I uploaded all the files and ready to install.

I'm running php 7.2

Not sure what causes this error, or what to do next to troubleshoot it.

Comment: Could be a hosting problem. But looking in your error.log file is the first step. And posting the errors here is the second step.

Comment: Thanks, I found the error log and looked it, found the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So, wow, after examining the error log it looks like the FTP failed to upload all the files.